# Remove the nan columns from the right-side of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove the nan **blank** columns from the right side of dataframe.
sample dataframe structure:

```
nan   A     B     C     nan     nan    nan
nan  Singh raj   roy    1       nan    nan
nan  rax   rqa   1      3       nan    nan
```

I am trying to remove the nan columns which is completely empty from the right side of the data frame.

expected output:

```
nan   A     B     C     nan  
nan  Singh raj   roy    1       
nan  rax   rqa   1      3
```

Can anyone help me to achieve result.

Answer (score 0):

You need test last only `NaN`s columns by invert position, test for non missing values and add cumulative sum, then test for not `0` and remove rows in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
#if nan are strings
#mask = df.iloc[:, ::-1].ne('nan').cumsum(axis=1).ne(0).any()
mask = df.iloc[:, ::-1].notna().cumsum(axis=1).ne(0).any()

df = df.loc[:, mask[::-1]]
print (df)
    0      1    2    3    4
0 NaN      A    B    C  NaN
1 NaN  Singh  raj  roy  1.0
2 NaN    rax  rqa    1  3.0
```

Another idea is back filling missing values and test if each column has at least one non `NaN` value:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.bfill(axis=1).notna().any()]
print (df)
    0      1    2    3    4
0 NaN      A    B    C  NaN
1 NaN  Singh  raj  roy  1.0
2 NaN    rax  rqa    1  3.0
```

Comment: But my column name is also nan.

Comment: @Rishav - if column name is `nan` it is important? For me it working for any value.

Comment: this type of data I am creating because I am performing slicing in the dataframe after loading the file without Header.

Comment: @Rishav - yop, it is good idea, I do same before lod your data to my solution.

Comment: earlier I am removing like df=df.loc[:,df.columns.notnull()] but this is removing every columns which have nan. As I am getting the data using slicing in the large dataframe.